# How can I delete/format partitions during Windows install from USB?--getting errors

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, formatting, bootable-media, reinstall

My Windows 10 'winload.efi' became corrupted and I opted to clean install using the Windows media creator tool to create a bootable USB. Upon booting from USB, I chose custom install and proceeded to delete down to one partition followed by a format of that partition (as I had done for other clean install of windows 7/XP). Unfortunately, there was an error thrown and Windows could not install, leaving me stranded without an OS. From a mac, I created another bootable USB from a complete Windows 10 iso file. 
The Windows installer boots, unfortunately when I attempt to delete or format any of the partitions:
        {
          Drive 0 Partition 1: Recovery,
          Drive 0 Partition 2: System,
          Drive 0 Partition 3: MSR,
          Drive 0 Partition 4: Primary,
        }
the installer throws the following errors:

"We couldn't delete the selected partition. [Error: 0x80070001]"

"We couldn't format the selected partition. [Error: 0x80070057]"

I have tried 'shift + F10' as recommended elsewhere to bring up a command prompt but not such prompt appears (presumably because I don't have a functioning OS anymore).

What can I do without an OS? How can I format the partitions and install from the bootable USB? Can this be done from BIOS?  I'm working from a Lenovo T580 laptop. Thank You.

Comment: The fact you cannot delete the partitions indicate your storage device itself might have a problem.  This would explain the reason a required file to boot Windows became corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try not formatting that one remaining partition but to delete it and than create a new one, on which then the Windows installation would go. If that doesn't work, you could try to boot a Linux Distro from the USB, format the drive then try again the installation of Windows. A quick tutorial for that can be found on this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199225/how-to-format-partition-new-hdd-for-windows) third answer. One more thing to check would be the sata and power cables that are attached to the drive.